# Objective-C, inheritance between functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

What I want is to inherit `trueCount` and `falseCount` values from func1 to func2 as you can see in the code below.
Any help on how to do that ?

```
- (void)func1 {
    int trueCount = 0;
    int falseCount = 0;

    if (test3) {        
        trueCount++;
    } else {
        falseCount++;
    }

    if (trueCount >= falseCount) {
        NSLog(@"TRUE WINS !!";   
    } else if (trueCount < falseCount) {
        NSLog(@"False WINS !!");
    }
}

- (void)func2 {
    ///HOW to make trueCount AND falseCount work here too, so that they inherit the same value in func1 ??

    if (trueCount >= falseCount) {
        NSLog(@"Show 1 !!";
    } else if (trueCount < falseCount) {
        NSLog(@"Show 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: These are in a class, yes? So use instance variables...

Comment: Can you tell me explain how ? I mean can you explain more, a small code snippet will be very helpful as I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does not show functions, it shows methods. Neither methods nor functions can be inherited - only classes can inherit other classes. However, nothing stops you from *calling* one method from inside another method to share the results produced by it. You could also move the shared functionality into a "helper" method, and use it in both places, like this:

```
// Define the shared method. Note the use of pointers.
-(void)countTrue:(int*)trueCount andFalse:(int*)falseCount {
    *trueCount = 0;
    *falseCount = 0;
    if (test3) {        
        *trueCount++;
    } else {
        *falseCount++;
    }
}
- (void)func1 {
    int trueCount;
    int falseCount;
    // Invoke the shared functionality from the first place in your code
    [self countTrue:&trueCount andFalse:&falseCount];
    if (trueCount >= falseCount) {
        NSLog(@"TRUE WINS !!";   
    } else if (trueCount < falseCount) {
        NSLog(@"False WINS !!");
    }
}
- (void)func2 {
    int trueCount;
    int falseCount;
    // Invoke the shared functionality from a second place in your code
    [self countTrue:&trueCount andFalse:&falseCount];
    if (trueCount >= falseCount) {
        NSLog(@"Show 1 !!";
    } else if (trueCount < falseCount) {
        NSLog(@"Show 2");
    }
}
```

Now the logic of counting is placed in a single place, so you do not need to repeat it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do something like this in your header:

```
@inteface GameCounter

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger trueCount;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger falseCount;

@end
```

and then use `self.trueCount` and `self.falseCount`

Comment: I've done the same, but the problem is that I can not Obtain the incremented value (new value) generated in `func1` this is where I am stuck ! I want to get the final, incremented value generated by `func1` and show it in `func2`

Comment: Are func1 and func2 in the same class?

Answer (score 1):

This question really has nothing to do with iOS or Objective-C. It is an Object Oriented question.

You have methods in a class. Those methods operate on some state, configuring, modifying and querying that state. Your methods (they aren't functions) are called without parameters, so no state is being added. Your class should have state of its own.

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger trueCount;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger falseCount;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL test3;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)method1 {
    if (self.test3) {        
        self.trueCount++;
    } else {
        self.falseCount++;
    }

    if (self.trueCount >= self.falseCount) {
        NSLog(@"TRUE WINS !!";   
    } else if (self.trueCount < self.falseCount) {
        NSLog(@"False WINS !!");
    }
}

- (void)method2 {
    if (self.trueCount >= self.falseCount) {
        NSLog(@"Show 1 !!";
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Show 2");
    }
}

@end
```